# Travis not installing npm modules

Tags: npm, travis-ci

I'm new to travis- I'm trying to get it to install my npm modules for my project and can't even get past that.  "npm install" and "npm test" work fine on my computer (a mac).  However, when I push my commits to travis it complains that:

```
Error: No compatible version found: ini@'^1.2.0'
Valid install targets:
npm ERR! ["1.0.0","1.0.1","1.0.2","1.0.3","1.0.4","1.0.5","1.1.0","1.2.0","1.2.1","1.3.0"]
```

Note that ini is not something I was originally including in my package.json, but it is depended on by something that I am using.  I tried explicitly adding the 1.2.0 version of ini to my package.json but it still complains.  I get similar complaints about other upstream dependencies.

Is there something about how travis is doing npm install that greatly differs from my local machine where it is working fine?  Really stumped here.

Here's a link to my latest travis failed build: https://travis-ci.org/infomofo/chrome-angular-md-template/builds/35592993

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to the NPM version coming with Node.js 0.8. It doesn't support the `^` syntax for declaring dependecies.

You could either use Node.js instead:

```
node_js: 0.10
```

Or you could update npm, which would bring support for the dependency version:

```
before_install: npm update -q
```